# how to Navigate from one cell to next view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I want my app to have 5 rows and each row has a particular height. Each row has a title, subtitle and an image. Then i want to be able to navigate to the next page when i tap on either of the rows(for e.g say 3rd row). how do i do this?

Comment: i know u can add images and labels using custom cells, but is there any other way i can do that in the table view?

Comment: still i don't know how i'm going to navigate to the next page by selecting a particular row, i mean each row will navigate to different page, rather will shoe different data, so how do i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to your 2nd part of the question is the initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle…. this one allows you to have a title and subtitle.  For the image, each cell has already built-in.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    NSString *title = (@"your title");
    NSString *subTitle = (@"your subtitle");
    cell.textLabel.text = title;   //title
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = subTitle;   //subtitle
    NSString *filePath = //file path to your image
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    cell.imageView.image = [myThumbnailClass image];  //image
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if(indexPath.row==0)
{
 singleProductViewController=[[SingleProductViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SingleProductViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:singleProductViewController animated:YES];
[singleProductViewController release];
}
else if(indexPath.row==1)
{
//Sec view Navigation
}
//Like wise u go on


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use method for handle tableview touch

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
}
```

You can check `indexPath` which row taped.

See this tutorial - [Navigating a Data Hierarchy With Table Views](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use the tableview delegate method

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
    {    
        singleProductViewController=[[SingleProductViewController alloc]initWithNibName: @"SingleProductViewController" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:singleProductViewController animated:YES];
        [singleProductViewController release];       
    }
```

SingleProductViewController is the new view you want to navigate

All the best

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpful, but still that doesn't answer my whole question :p, if you could also help me out with the other part, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: by the "other part" i mean, how do i insert image and label or anything else in the cells without using custom cells? is that possible?

Comment: the tableview cell has a title,description and image properties by default. If you want more label is a cell you want to customize your cell.